# Google Cloud Code -- connect to cloud sql db using cloud proxy with iam impersonation

Tags: google-cloud-code, google-cloud-intellij

Is there a way to connect to google cloud db using cloud sql proxy iam impersonation?

I can see the options for connecting to cloud sql instance using the proxy, but not how to do so using iam impersonation -------------------

Answer (score 1):

I found I can just specify the cloud_sql_proxy command in the command window and then create a datasource in pycharms tooling to connect.

Comment: You are correct, Cloud Code only connects using public and private IP at the moment, but not IAM. See similar request here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/3166 and upvote. Otherwise your approach works.